# Playing with form elements with setvisible method

Tags: java, visibility

I am currently developing a program in Java SE and in my program, the buttons, labels, textfield are changing continiously because of the nature of the project. Eventually, I have realized that there are to many setvisible true-false in source code. I have to play with all the components. Is it a good programming principle and as an alternative, do you guys suggest me something to increase the quality of the work.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: @niceman this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't play a lot with the function setVisible. (But sometimes it the best/easiest way and depend your logic between your elements).
To minimize it and better OOP programming is to use JPanle to group your elements together when it relevant.